# Using embed code to create HTML file -- Google Calendar

Tags: html, google-api, google-calendar-api, html4

Okay, so I recently set up a Google account for use at my job. We are using Google Calendar to set up the schedules for the meeting rooms. What I have been doing is using the XML to make the events viewable to anyone. However, I want to use the embed code to just create an HTML file (because the calendar has a much nicer UI, unlike the boring list of events like the XML is).

The XML/HTML file is stored on a public folder on our server, so anyone has access to it and can check the schedule at any time.

My problem is that I am terrible at programming (I've taken only two classes on it), so I don't know how to set up an authentication system to "log in" and make the calendars viewable (especially not in HTML). I could probably get around this by just making the calendars public, but I would prefer not to do that. Is there any way to include the account username and password in the HTML code, perhaps using the Google API? Specifically, I've been trying with HTML4 Strict, but I'm certainly open to other options.

If anyone has any tips or can kind of walk me through the process, that would be awesome! ♥

EDIT: Here is the code I have so far. It works, as long as I log into Google first.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Training Room Schedule</title>
   </head>
   <iframe src="embed_URL_is_here"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to do this is to make the calendar public (as you mentioned), and then follow the instructions [here](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41207).

If you can't make it public, I would suggest taking a look at [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), which has a GCal extension and would include the functionality you're looking for. The documentation has an [example of embedding a Google Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/).